# Access mtp devices in KDE plasma terminal

Tags: command-line, kde, mtp

I can easily access my galaxy tab on kde plasma ubuntu 20.04 by restarting Dolphin with the address /Galaxy Tab A (mtp).

I wish to access my tab(mtp) with kde terminal also in order to perform rsync operations to sync data for editing between laptop and tablet.

Kindly guide me on this matter.

Comment: MTP (Media Transfer Protocol) devices has no "filesystem" so might need some trickery to make them accessible by software that expects to see a filesystem (a block device)... reading trhis: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol - I conclude that this is yet another of the non-standard (ISO, RFC, ...) thing invented at Microsoft. By this they probably avoid some kind of licensing(!?) for MS-DOS/FAT ;-)  - or maybe, just scrapping the old code for FAT.

Comment: I don't know about KDE, but in GNOME they "mounted" under `/run/user/<user_id>/gvfs/mtp:host=<device_name>/` "directory".

Comment: There exists no guide in mounting mtp under kde plasma.

Comment: @pasmon79 I figured this out, I think but "it aint easy," and I'm trying to finish my solution off right now. ... MAYBE I can get it done tonight... If successful, I'll post an answer!

Comment: @pasmon79 Unfortunately, with far too many hours invested, it hasn't worked. I'm about to try just removing KDE Connect entirely. -ugh!-